# Python & Mysql query issue - wrong result

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to use mysql in my python code but when I run a select query in the code, I get a wrong result.

Here is my app.py code:

```
import web
import pymysql
import createdb

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        createdb.createTables()
        result = createdb.select()
        return render.index(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Here is my createdb.py code:

```
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             port=3306,
                             user='root',
                             password='xxxx',
                             db='mysql',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def createTables():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE words(id INT, name VARCHAR(255))")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(1, 'look')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(2, 'book')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(3, 'try')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(4, 'read')")


def select():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    selectResult = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM words WHERE id = 3")
    return selectResult

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createTables()
```

Here is my index.html code:

```
$def with (name)

$if name:
    I just wanted to say <em>hello</em> to $name.
$else:
    <em>Hello</em>, world!
```

In my case, I am expecting a result like this one;

> I just wanted to say *hello* to try.

However, I am getting the below result;

> I just wanted to say *hello* to 1.

After I run the application, I checked my mysql workbench and saw that the database is created as *mydatabase* but the table was not created. However after I stop and re-run the application, I got a error saying that the database already exists. That is fine, then I put a comment in front of that line which creates the db. After I re-run the app, then another error occurs and it says that the *words* table already exists. As I said before, when I checked mysql workbench, there was no such table. Maybe this wrong query result is related with this issue. That is why I wanted to explain it in detail.

Could you please tell me what is wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in Python but at the terminal I would have to say `use mydatabase;`, i.e. `create database X; use X; create table ...;` so that MySQL knows _where_ to create the table. I think when omitting the `use` the tables will get created in some default schema.

Comment: You have to call `.fetchone()` or `.fetchall()` e.g. `cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM words WHERE id = 3").fetchone()`

Comment: I tried that but I got an error like `<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> at /
'int' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`. I think the problem is that I cannot create the table because when I check my mysql workbench, I cannot find the related table under my database.

Comment: @bernie I solved the problem with `fetchone()` function. I think I was using it wrong. That is why it did not work. Thank you. However, now I get a result like `I just wanted to say hello to {u'name': u'try'}.`. As I said earlier, I am expecting something like this one: `I just wanted to say hello to try.`. What is that **u** letter there and why my column name shows up in the result?

Answer (score 0):

After I changed my createdb.py code, I solved my problem. Here is the modified version of it;

```
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             port=3306,
                             user='root',
                             password='xxxxx',
                             db='mydatabase',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def createTables():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE words(id INT, name VARCHAR(255))")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(1, 'look')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(2, 'book')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(3, 'try')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO words(id, name) VALUES(4, 'read')")
    connection.commit()

def select():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM words WHERE id = 3")
    selectResult = cursor.fetchone()
    value = "%s" % (selectResult["name"])
    return value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createTables()
    connection.close()
```

Not, I get the result that I want:

> I just wanted to say *hello* to try.